# Extract values from dictionary using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data in this format:

```
{'data': [{'ask': 8880.6,
           'bid': 8866.1,
           'high': '9888.8',
           'last': '8893.2',
           'low': '7500',
           'pair': 'BTC:USD',
           'timestamp': '1517580261',
           'volume': '4959.57424274',
           'volume30d': '55778.24679612'},
          {'ask': 979.98,
           'bid': 965.05,
           'high': '1187.57',
           'last': '965.02',
           'low': '756.02',
           'pair': 'ETH:USD',
           'timestamp': '1517580261',
           'volume': '19125.87672400',
           'volume30d': '306271.85175700'},
          {'ask': 1177.99,
           'bid': 1118.03,
           'high': '1406.67',
           'last': '1179.17',
           'low': '970',
           'pair': 'BCH:USD',
           'timestamp': '1517580261',
           'volume': '1313.36298096',
           'volume30d': '26008.22405422'}]
```

what i want is is only the first values of "ask, bid, high, last, low, pair, timestamp, volume, volume30d" dynamically, because the data updates and I want the code to provide these values dynamically.

Comment: if your dictionary is `d`, have you tried `d['data'][0]` ?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis thanks for ur response and yeah i've tried that but it shows me "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: @HadiRajani are you putting quotes around the number 1 or 0?

Comment: also check your code please. should there a close curly bracket at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your inner dictionaries are in a list, you can first index the list and then pull out the values of `ask`, `bid`, `high`, `last`, `low`, `pair`, `timestamp`, `volume`, `volume30d`.

For example (say this dictionary structure is called `dict`):

```
dict['data'][0]['ask']  # this will get you the first occurrence of 'ask'
```

You can do the same thing to get the other values for the keys of `bid`, `high`, `last`, `low`, `pair`, `timestamp`, `volume`, `volume30d`.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.